# PCA and LDA for predicting metallurgical behaviour?

Tags: classification, pca, discriminant-analysis, chemometrics

I'm a geology student and I'm currently doing my thesis at a mining company. I've been asked to search the chemical variables (basically chemical elements) that negatively impact the most on the metallurgical process. I've got a small database (100 representative samples of the mine with their chemical analysis and metallurgical data).

I'm already quite clear on which elements are nocive for the process thanks to PCA. Nevertheless, I want to go a little further and generate a model capable of predict the metallurgical behaviour of new samples based on their geochemichal variables (elements).

I've been *playing* with LDA but, how I said, I'm a geologist and I don't have a solid mathematical/stadistical formation so I've got some doubts on the number of predictors/variables to consider as input. Until now I've getting acceptable results (~80% effectivity classifying groups, cross validated) considering **all** variables as input (21 predictors).

Referring to that, 2 questions:

1) For the LDA effectivity, is it better more or less predictors? Must I consider just the most influential variables that I have already detected, or all variables (21) for better classification?

2) Do you recommend me any other predictive/classification technique? I would be so greatful.

Any leads, suggestions about my approach would be very helpful, thanks in advance!